# How to toggle size of responsive images, with a twist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up a fiddle with the functionality I am after, however I cannot figure out how to achieve the same result when the images have a percentage-based width.

http://jsfiddle.net/bs8Tw/

```
$('img').click(function() {

    var toggleWidth = $(this).width() == 350 ? '700px' : '350px';

    $('img').animate({ width: '350px' });
    $(this).animate({ width: toggleWidth });

});
```

As you can see, when an image is clicked, it doubles in width. When it is clicked again, it returns to its normal size. The key here, however, is that if one image is clicked, then another, the first image returns to its normal size before the second image increases.

Basically, I am looking for this exact functionality, but I would like the image to toggle between a 50% and 100% width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your question is more about "how can I determine whether the width is 50% or not."  Well it's pretty simple: just check whether it's 50% the width of the container.  In fact, since it will otherwise be 100% of the width, you can just check whether it's less than 60% the width of the container.

```
var toggleWidt = $(this).width() < $(this).parent().width() * .6 ? '100%' : '50%'
```

This does assume that the "container" is the maximum size you want for the images, but you can always use `.closest` if it's something higher up than the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/bs8Tw/2/